# Any Dictionary that can handle dupes?

Tags: c#, .net

I am parsing a test file, in for form of:

`[Person]: [Name]-[John Doe], [Age]-[113], [Favorite Color]-[Red].`

`[Person]: [Name]-[John Smith], [Age]-[123], [Favorite Color]-[Blue].`

`[Person]: [Name]-[John Sandles], [Age]-[133], [Favorite Color]-[Green].`

`[Person]: [Name]-[Joe Blogs], [Age]-[143], [Favorite Color]-[Khaki].`

As you can see, the values are not duplicated (though I want to account for future dupes), but the Keys are dupes. The keys being the parts before the hyphen (-).

But everytime I get these into a Dictionary it has a fit and tells me dupes aren't allowed. Why doesn't the Dictionary allow dupes? And how can I overcome this?

Comment: `As you can see, the values are not duplicated` so use value as dictionary key .

Comment: It should allow duplicates on value side, but not on the key side.

Comment: But I need to account for dupes (either key or value)

Comment: Are you sure you need to use a Dictionary then? If you are, then you'll have to look into implementing your own and do collision handling

Comment: if you need dupes why you using dictionary at all?

Comment: It's not clear to be what you are actually trying to do, but a [`Lookup`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534291.aspx) gives you similar functionality to a `Dictionary`, but allows associating multiple values with the same key.

Comment: To me, what you're doing there just looks like a standard `Person`-object with a `Name`-property, an `Age`-property and a `Favorite Color`-property. Can you try elaborate what you're trying to do?

Comment: @veredesmarald: Problem is: You can't instantiate that class as it doesn't have a public constructor.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth Not directly, but it's not hard to create a list of key-value pairs and call `ToLookup` on it. Or you can just use a `Dictionary` with lists as the values. It's hard to give advice on the best approach here without a better description of the problem.

Comment: @AskeB. - True, though the data is not always the same. There may be more, less or even other Property names and there's no telling what they may be.

Answer (score 1):

The Dictionary has the TKey part of it being hashed for fast lookup, if you have dupes in there, you'll get into collisions and complexities, which will reduce your ability to look things up quickly and efficiently.  That is why dupes are not allowed.

You could make a struct with the data in it, and put that in a `Dictionnary<ID, MyStruct>` for example.  This way you avoid dupes in the key (which is unique for each struct, and you have all your data in a Dictionary.

Comment: It will not different to MyStruct[] for usability but will be slower and takes more memory.

Answer (score 1):

Dictionary can have dupes in value but cannot have dupes in Key because then how will you tell which key's value do you want.

> And how can I overcome this

use a `KeyvaluePair[]` but in that case also how will you tell which key's value do you want?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Wintellect Power Collections' MultiDictionary class. Power Collections is a long-established set of collection classes for .Net 2 or later. It hasn't been updated for 5 years, but it doesn't need to be.

See here: http://powercollections.codeplex.com/

Download it here: http://powercollections.codeplex.com/releases/view/6863

Answer (score 0):

The simplest thing to do is to use an `Dictionary<string, List<string>>`.

Usage:

```
foreach(var person in persons)
{
    List<string> list;
    if(!dict.TryGetValue(person.Key, out list)
    {
        list = new List<string>();
        dict.Add(person.Key, list);
    }

    list.Add(person.Data);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`Lookup<TKey, TElement>` class from  `System.Linq` namespace represents a collection of keys each mapped to one or more values. More info: [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb460184.aspx)

```
List<Person> list= new List<Person>();
// ...
var lookup = list.ToLookup(person => person.Key, person => new {Age=person.Age, Color=person.Color});

IEnumerable<Person> peopleWithKeyX = lookup["X"];

public class Person
{
    public string Key { get; set; }
    public string Age { get; set; }
    public string Color { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: This answer is only helpful if you add how the OP should instantiate that class, as it doesn't have a public constructor.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your question I suppose that you are using [Name], [Age] and [Favorite Color] as keys. There are many ways how to put your data into the dictionary using these keys, but the real question is how will you get it back?

The keys in Dictionary should be unique, so you need to find some unique data to use it as a key.
In your case the test file looks like list of Persons, where each line contains person's data. So the most natural way is to compose a dictionary that contains rows about persons where 'unique data' should be a Person's name, unless it is not duplicated.

*In real life however Person's name is usually a bad choice, (not only because it may change over time, but also because the probability of identical names is very high), so artificial keys are used instead (row number, Guids, etc.)*

**Edit** I see that number of properties may vary. So you need to use nested dictionaries. Outer - for 'Persons' and inner for Person properties:

```
Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>> person_property_value;
```

However for your data structure to be more understandable you should put the inner dictionary inside Person class:

```
class Person{
    public readonly Dictionary<string, string> props;

    public Person()
    {
        props = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    }
}
```

Now you add the Person as:

```
Person p = new Person();
p.props['Name'] = 'John Doe';
p.props['Age'] = 'age';
dictionary.Add('John Doe', p);
```

And get it back as:

```
Person p = dictionary[Name];
```

Now to allow several persons share the same name you declare the dictionary as `Dictionary<string, List<Person>>`